# File collision w/aws-amplify and react-native. All attempts at path exclusion yield no result

Tags: react-native, aws-amplify, metro-bundler

What it says on the tin, basically. I have a react-native project using aws-amplify as the backend all attempts at excluding the offending path in metro.config.js result in no change.

```
metro-file-map: Haste module naming collision: InstagramPostConfirmation
  The following files share their name; please adjust your hasteImpl:
    * <rootDir>/amplify/#current-cloud-backend/function/sendConfirmation/src/package.json
    * <rootDir>/amplify/backend/function/sendConfirmation/src/package.json
```

My metro.config.js:

```
const { getDefaultConfig } = require('expo/metro-config');
const { mergeConfig } = require('@react-native/metro-config');

/**
 * Metro configuration
 * https://facebook.github.io/metro/docs/configuration
 *
 * @type {import('metro-config').MetroConfig}
 */
const config = {};

const exclusionList = require('metro-config/src/defaults/exclusionList');
module.exports = {
    resolver: {
      blockList: exclusionList([/#current-cloud-backend\/.*/]),
    },
    transformer: {
      getTransformOptions: async () => ({
        transform: {
          experimentalImportSupport: false,
          inlineRequires: false,
        },
      }),
    },
  };

module.exports = mergeConfig(getDefaultConfig(__dirname), config);
```

I've attempted many permutation of exclusionList, blockList, blackListRE, etc in my my metro.config.js to try and exclude the #cloudbackend path. No results.

Addendum, forgot to include package.json:

```
  "name": "notjustphotos",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.19.1",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^9.4.1",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "^2.4.10",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.8",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.6.3",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.7",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.13",
    "amazon-cognito-identity-js": "^6.3.1",
    "aws-amplify": "^5.3.5",
    "aws-amplify-react-native": "^7.0.2",
    "expo": "^49.0.6",
    "expo-camera": "~13.4.2",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.45.1",
    "react-native": "0.72.1",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^5.6.0",
    "react-native-pager-view": "^6.2.0",
    "react-native-picker-select": "^8.0.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.7.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.22.1",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.5.2",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "react-native-video": "^5.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.0",
    "@react-native/eslint-config": "^0.72.2",
    "@react-native/metro-config": "^0.72.9",
    "@tsconfig/react-native": "^3.0.0",
    "@types/metro-config": "^0.76.3",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.24",
    "@types/react-native-vector-icons": "^6.4.13",
    "@types/react-native-video": "^5.0.15",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.2.1",
    "eslint": "^8.19.0",
    "jest": "^29.2.1",
    "metro-config": "^0.77.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.76.5",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "^4.8.4"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=16"
  }
}
```

Comment: The issue is in my metro.config.js, and it is obvious, and I am embarrassed. Default assignment of the module.exports was at the bottom -_-